How to create notifying icon on process boxes in VBA on Visio?
I'm new to VBA with some previous coding experience. I'm doing a job task with Visio (yay).
Is it possible to mimic something like these icons (dark blue ones in 1st pic) in Visio? I'd need to indicate certain things on specific process boxes. I found some indicator labels from More Shapes -menu (2nd pic). I'd like to do my own, with few extra specs: It would suit my purposes to add text in them (running notation numbering, ie 3.1, 3.12) and I'd like my icons possibly to be part of the box frame. I'm not sure if this can be done, but I'd be happy to hear suggestions on what code to use.
1: Image of the icons (from another sw) indicating other features

2: Some shapes I could add in Visio, didn't meet my need

Thank you for any hints and comments!

You can add some sub-shapes into your box.

You don't need VBA for this. You can use "data graphics" to decorate your (process?) shapes with icons. The location of the icon(s) is configurable, you can set it to be also in the bottom-lower corner like on your screenshots.
If you don't see in the stock options the icons you need, you can add your own. Here is an article by David Parker how to do it step by step:
https://bvisual.net/2012/04/19/make-your-own-visio-data-graphic-icons-sets-automatically/

do you mean David J Parker?

Thanks Nikolay, these seem to work ok for my purposes. I've been busy with other stuff a couple of days and have yet to checked whether I can add the running reference numbering in these. Maybe even, but it's also not necessary. Funny enough, I had studied stuff from Parker's blog before, but hadn't come across to this post. (I can't upvote your comment due to being a newbie, but yay either way)
